# Find the bases relative in which TD matrix is in diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$D$ is the differentiation operator. $V$ is the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq 3$. $T$ is the linear transformation that maps $p(x)$ to $xp'(x)$. $W$ is the image of $V$ under $TD$

Find the bases for $V,W$ s.t. the matrix $TD$ is diagonal.

Ans: $V = (x^3,x^2,x,1)$ and $W = (x^2,x)$. The matrix $TD =\left(\begin{array}{cccc}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 2 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

I still don't see the steps I need to take to derive the answer.

So here's how I'm approaching the problem: 
The first basis element of $V$ = $x^3$.

$D(x^3) = 3x^2.$ $3T(x^2) = 3x^22x = 6x^3$. Thus, the first column of TD = $(6,0)^T$. This means that the first basis element of W is $6x^3$, which is wrong.

Comment: Note that $TD(x^3)$ is a *multiple* of $x^2$.  Same for $x^2$ and $x$.  $x$ and $1$ are in the kernel of $TD$.

Comment: Okay. ...? How is this supposed to help.

Comment: Choosing basis elements in this way makes the matrix diagonal, which is what we want.

Comment: So I'm not finding this helpful. (not your fault.) I added some stuff about how I'm currently trying to solve the problem. It's giving me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the computation:
$$
T(p(x)) = xp'(x) \neq p(x) p'(x)
$$
In particular, we have
$$
T(x^2) = x(2x) = 2x^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did to figure the 
$$TD:\matrix {x^3 &\to & 3x^2  \to & 6x^2\\x^2&\to & 2x  \to & 2x\\
x &\to & 1  \to & 0\\1 &\to & 0  \to & 0}$$

now you can write the matrix representation of $TD$ with respect to the basis $\{x^3 , x^2, x, 1\}$ and $\{x^2, x\}$ as $$\pmatrix{6&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0}$$